# Cygwin doesn't display Python output

Tags: windows, python, cygwin

I installed Cygwin through https://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe and using all the default settings.

Cygwin doesn't display Python output:

[image]

I would have expected instead:

[image]

What could the issue be?

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate, Cygwin installed through setup.exe version 2.883 (64-bit), and Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit) (that is the default version of python in Cygwin).

[image]

Comment: Are you using windows python from cygwin?

Comment: @CodeIt I didn't know that was possible, but that sounds likely. How to check? I do have the same python version on Windows, so I am pretty sure you're right.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250749/using-windows-python-from-cygwin) might help you.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt `which python`

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks, the output is `/cygdrive/c/Anaconda/python` so it's confirmed that Codelt was correct. I wasn't aware that Cygwin was accessing Windows' PATH as fallback. That's good to know!